# show gmail screen directly... not thru selection

Tags: android, email, gmail

I am sort of new to android.
I am trying to send a msg via gmail and this is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);  
String uriText;  
uriText = "mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=Subject&body=this is test.";  
uriText = uriText.replace(" ", "%20");  
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);   
intent.setData(uri);  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select mailer"));
```

It works. But, before sending the msg, it shows a selection box
and asks me to choose either gmail or email.
How can I skip the selection box ?

Any help would be so appreciated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I skip the selection box ?

You don't. You allow the user to choose what application they wish to use to send the message. Some users do not use Gmail.

Comment: Point taken.. thanks for your reply. But I still wanna know how to skip it. Can you give me some clue ?